# Oracle trim whitespace on the inside of a string

Tags: sql, oracle, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am storing phone numbers as VARCHAR2 in my system to allow for users to input '+' characters infront of their phone number if they so choose.

My regexp allows for this perfectly, but when storing the number in the database I want to strip out all whitespace the user may enter.

My regexp allows for the following formats

```
+4470123456789
+447 0123456789
+447 01234 56789
01234567890
01234 567890
01234 567 890
```

I know I could resolve my issue by not letting users put any whitespace in their numbers, but I know from personal experience just how frustrating it is to have a validation error due to some silly formatting on the client side.  I have tried using the TRIM function on my INSERT/UPDATE trigger but I have realised that is limited to only front and trailing whitespace, is there any other function in Oracle I could use that would remove internal whitespace? Or do I need to write my own function to do this?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You want to try `replace (telno, ' ', '')`.

Comment: Hi , what can i do if i want to replace the space and convert phone number from varchar2 to number?

Comment: `to_number(replace(telno, ' ', ''))`

Answer (score 7):

a better approach is to use a regular expression to remove all spaces within a string

```
SQL> with t as (
    select 'AAA    BBB CCC' col from dual union
    select 'DDDD EEE     F' col from dual 
    )
    --
    -- actual query:
    --
    select regexp_replace(col, '[[:space:]]+', chr(32)) col
    from   t;
```

### COL

AAA BBB CCC
DDDD EEE F

Comment: Why do you suggest that regular expression is better than replace()?  Regular expression processing is much more CPU intensive in general.

Comment: Do not understand why people are forcing themselves to use regular expression on such a simple need.

Comment: This regex answer collapses whitespace vs the replace answer removes whitespace in the middle.  Regex can accomplish either answer's solution whereas replace cannot.

Comment: The regex answer includes all forms of whitespace (space, tab, vertical space) whereas the simple replace only catches space characters. In other words, for example, tabs will be ignored I believe.